# How this queries will be evaluated? and, join syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, join, syntax, evaluation

How this queries will be evaluated?
(what i ask is: what will be the logic that the db-engine will use to gather the data?)?

A:

```
SELECT tableA.* FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.key1 = tableA.key1
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.key2 = tableB.key2
```

B:

```
SELECT tableA.* FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableC 
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON (tableB.key1 = tableA.key1) AND (tableC.key2 = tableB.key2)
```

C:
What is the syntax, for joining multiple tables? (A and B for example)

D:
What is the logic behind the order of joins?
(How different joins (left, and inner) should be combines in a query?)

ANY-one?

Comment: The syntax of `B` is wrong. Please explain what do you mean by that ? Each join requites `ON` clause after the table name, the correct syntax is: `... table1 [LEFT|RIGHT|INNER] JOIN table2 ON conditions [ [LEFT|RIGHT|INNER] JOIN table3 ON conditions]` etc. Only the `CROSS JOIN` has no `ON conditions` clause.

Comment: @kordirko It is exactly my question: it works. but i am not sure what does it mean.

Comment: @kordirko - That is not correct for MySQL. Syntax is fine for `b`. Each JOIN does **not require** an `ON` clause (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Without an `ON` clause, a JOIN/ INNER JOIN becomes a CROSS JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tableA.* FROM tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.key1 = tableA.key1
INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.key2 = tableB.key2
```

Since no brackets are used this should be evaluated left-to-right, so:

```
SELECT tableA.* 
FROM 
(tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.key1 = tableA.key1)
        INNER JOIN tableC ON tableC.key2 = tableB.key2
```

Meaning you first select *all* records from table A, with the matching records from B if they exist (outer join). That result set is then joined with C, but since you join on B.Key, all previous records where B = null will now disappear.
I am quite sure that the first join could be an inner join, giving the same result.

```
SELECT tableA.* FROM tableA
INNER JOIN tableC 
LEFT JOIN tableB
ON (tableB.key1 = tableA.key1) AND (tableC.key2 = tableB.key2)
```

Now we first cross-join every record from A with every record from C (cartesian product). 
That (possibly huge and possibly meaningless) resultset we extend with data from B where we can find it (meaning we add a record from B wherever we have a match with either A or B).

In general, when joining several tables, just take it step by step and always try to realize what you are joining with what. When in doubt, use brackets :)